# PHP MYSQL - Search comma separated list with a comma separated list

Tags: php, mysql

Dear Stackoverflowers,

I have a mysql query which checks if some sub categories are part of a categoryID to show all products from subcategories in the main category.

For example:

1. Category

   - Subcategory 1
   - Subcategory 2
   - Subcategory 3

For example products are added to subcats but are ALL beeing shown in the head category.
This works fine and i do this with `WHERE cID in (' . $subids . ')`

But now comes it, the cID used to hold just one value but since it has to be possible to add products to multiple categories i now save the multiple selected ids as comma separated in the cID field.

So im searching for a way to basicly find a match from a comma seperated list within a comma separated list because cID has now become comma separated ID's and FIND_IN_SET does not work with this.

I hope someone can shine some light, thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

Have a read of these:

- [Many-to-many data model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29)
- [Junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)

Implementing this, as opposed to comma-separated values, should probably save you and your coworkers a lot of headache and simplify your queries, effectively eliminating the need of complex queries. It should be faster, too.

Comment: Just to help a little more, if you implement the many to many data model your query would probably look something like this: `SELECT * FROM table_a LEFT JOIN junction_table ON table_a.cID = junction_table.cID WHERE junction_table.subid IN ( $subids )`      You may want to also add `GROUP BY table_a.primary_key` so you get a distinct record from table_a even if there are multiple matched subids.

Answer (score 0):

Add full-text search index on this column in the database and then use following sql query
Ref - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 0):

Storing a CSV in a single field is not a good idea. Searching on that requires use of LIKE clause.

```
where CID LIKE '$cid1,' or CID LIKE ',$cid1,' or CID LIKE ',$cid1' or 
      CID LIKE '$cid2,' or CID LIKE ',$cid2,' or CID LIKE ',$cid2' or
      .... so on
```

Also FIND_IN_SET would work too.

```
where FIND_IN_SET( $cid1, CID ) OR FIND_IN_SET($cid2, CID) .. so on
```

Answer (score 0):

*i now save the multiple selected ids as comma separated in the cID field*. That's a very bad approach ,why would you store a CSV in a single field ,you shud change your design ,make a seperate table where each value will have a new row and will be mapped to a FK.

What you really need to do,is work on your DB design,read on Normalization and other related topics,I have so added some links,

1. [MSDN Link on Many to Many](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170463.aspx)
2. [Databae Normalization](http://www.phlonx.com/resources/nf3/)